# how i can get my current posiotion in alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I get my current position in AlertDialog

```
String text = String.format("Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getBearing());
this.locationText.setText(text);
```

thx for help

Comment: Please improve your question. You haven't show us what you have tried and posting the same question in title and body is not a good way to ask. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provide plenty of [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) on this subject.

The important thing to remember is that getting a users current location can take time, a lot of time if they are using GPS. There are multiple approaches you can take, however if you want to display a dialog with location info quickly you should use 'getLastKnownLocation', it may not be accurate, but it will be fast.